# Understanding resources and returning an object

Tags: angularjs

I am following a tutorial that is using `$resource`.

They are injecting the resource into a service. The service is then injected into the controller.

Do I need to use a service or can I just use a factory?

Also the actual resource that he uses, is in a factory of itself with just a few lines of code. Why inject this? Can't this be another function in the service? Or is the idea that you build up a factory full of other endpoints?

```
var contactFactory = function($resource){
        return $resource("https://endpoint.com/api/samples/v1/contact/:id/");
    };
```

Also he is building one big object in the service with functions inside as well the .get method and types such as booleans inside the object. Is this just a preference to build a service like this and to return one big object to your controller rather than accessing a list of functions?

```
'doOrder': function (order) {
            self.hasMore = true;
            self.page = 1;
            self.persons = [];
            self.ordering = order;
            self.loadContacts();
        },
        'loadContacts': function () {
            if (self.hasMore && !self.isLoading) {
                self.isLoading = true;

                var params = {
                    'page': self.page,
                    'search': self.search,
                    'ordering': self.ordering
                };

                Contact.get(params, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    angular.forEach(data.results, function (person) {
                        self.persons.push(new Contact(person));
                    });

                    if (!data.next) {
                        self.hasMore = false;
                    }
                    self.isLoading = false;
                });
            }

        },
```

Comment: What is the link to the tutorial?

Comment: It's Udemy video so its payed private